# Animate a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I us an XMLHttpRequest() to send data, I have a upload progress event which I have tested and does run:

```
function uploadProgress(event) {
            if(event.lengthComputable){
                var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
                console.log(complete);
                $('.meter').css('width', complete+'%');
            }

        };
```

The problem is, my progress bar jutters up, it goes from 0, 40%, 60%, 100%. Is there a way to smoothly animate it, ideally using CSS?

Comment: Use `.animate()` or CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `.width` in the CSS:

```
.meter{
  transition:width .4s;
  -webkit-transition:width .4s;
  -moz-transition:width .4s;
}
```

Read about transitions here ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions))

Alternatively, you can use jQuery:

```
$( ".meter" ).animate({
  width: complete+"%"
});
```

eg.

```
function uploadProgress(event) {
  if(event.lengthComputable){
    var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
    console.log(complete);
    $('.meter').animate({width:complete+"%"});
  }
};
```

Learn about jQuery animate here ([Link](https://api.jquery.com/animate/))

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions):

```
.meter {
  -webkit-transition: width 200ms ease-in-out 0ms;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}
```